# How print dataframe column names that have a particular value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently doing this for each column:

```
df['slope'].isin(['?'])
```

How do I print all columns that have at least one value `'?'`?

Data set looks like this:

```
age sex cp  trestbps    chol    fbs restecg thalach exang   oldpeak slope   ca  thal    target
0   28.0    1.0 2.0 130 132 0   2   185 0   0   ?   ?   ?   0
```

I'm looking for a function that will print `slope,ca,thal` (the ones that contains `'?'`)

Comment: Could you give an example of your data and desired output?

Comment: I've just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
df= df.loc[: , (df == '?').any()]
#or columns

col_list=df.loc[: , (df == '?').any()].columns.to_list()

#if you are looking "isin"
df= df.loc[: , df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('?').any(),axis=0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].astype('str').str.contains(r'\?').any():
       print(col)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[[x for x in df.columns if any(df[x].astype(str).str.contains(r"\?"))]]
```